# Invalid cast from 'Double' to 'DateTime' in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

![My error message how to fix this error,I have cheked my data table,procedure but I cant find this error

```
procedureName = "InvoiceDetails";
cmdType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvoiceNo", SqlDbType.Int));//0
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@H", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));//1
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", SqlDbType.Decimal ));//2
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExchangeRate", SqlDbType.Decimal));//3
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Hamount", SqlDbType.Decimal));//4
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HAWBAmountLKR", SqlDbType.Decimal));//5
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Discountamount ", SqlDbType.Decimal));//6
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DisType", SqlDbType.Int));//7
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CurrencyType", SqlDbType.VarChar,(10)));//8
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvoiceDatetime",SqlDbType.DateTime));//9
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fuel",SqlDbType.Decimal));//10
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Invoicecode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30));//11
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvoiceTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal));//12
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30));//13
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreateUserID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30));//14
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Int));//15

//Inserting data through stored procedure
parameters[0].Value = 1;//0
parameters[1].Value = DropDownh.SelectedValue.ToString();//1
parameters[2].Value = Double.Parse(txtvalue.Text.Trim());//2
parameters[3].Value = Double.Parse(txtexchage.Text.Trim());//3
parameters[4].Value = Double.Parse(txtUSD.Text.Trim());//4
parameters[5].Value = Double.Parse(txtLKR.Text.Trim());//5
parameters[6].Value = Double.Parse(txtfuel0.Text.Trim());//6
parameters[7].Value = DropDiz.SelectedValue.ToString();//7
parameters[8].Value = "USD";//8
parameters[9].Value = DateTime.Now;//DateStampLabel.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"); //9
parameters[10].Value = "0.00";//10
parameters[11].Value = "N/A";//11
parameters[12].Value = "0.00";//12
parameters[13].Value = LblcompCode.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''");//13
parameters[14].Value = LbluserName.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''");//14
parameters[15].Value = 0;//15
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9cPr.jpg)

Comment: Add breakpoints to your code, debug and find the error.

Comment: What line is giving the exception?

Comment: Can you add the stored procedure as well?

Comment: Are you certain it's the parameters and not the stored proc itself? Put a `return` in the start of that proc so you get the parameter values but skip the processing. Then try again.

Comment: I Add breakpoints get this error Invalid cast from 'Double' to 'DateTime' in asp.net,i check my stored procedure and data table it's ok. exception is  "Invalid cast from 'Double' to 'DateTime' "

Answer (score 4):

I doubt on `Parameter[7]` it should be `int`.
Try like this:

```
Int.Parse(DropDiz.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Comment: That would probably go for #10 and #12 too, but neither should generate that exact message.

Comment: same error{"Failed to convert parameter value from a Double to a DateTime."}

Comment: Comment all parameters from stored procedure and from code, and then as per  @hans-kesting said return from start of stored procedure. then uncomment each paramenter from both side one by one. it will help you to understand which parameter is problamatic